# WPF MediaElement Playback Orientation

Tags: wpf, mp4, mediaelement

I have some mp4s (captured on an android, some in portrait, some in landscape)
When I use them as the source of a MediaElement tag, they always play in landscape mode. I've been googling this like crazy and haven't found anything at all about the orientation of video in a MediaElement, so hopefully I missed something basic.

Here's my xaml:

```
<Canvas x:Name="videoCanvas" Height="Auto" Width="641" Margin="10,0,11,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding Media}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=videoCanvas}"  Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=videoCanvas}" />
</Canvas>
```

and the code-behind:

```
  media = new MediaElement();
  media.LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Manual;            
  media.Loaded += Media_Loaded;
  media.MediaOpened += Media_MediaOpened;
  media.Source = new Uri(@"c:\videos\portrait.mp4");
  media.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
  media.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
```

The NaturalVideoHeight/Width in Media_MediaOpened is the same for both videos so I don't think I can use that to rotate the MediaElement.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way I solved this problem in my case. You need to use nugget Microsoft-WindowsAPICodePack-Core and Microsoft-WindowsAPICodePack-Shell:

```
ShellFile shell = ShellFile.FromFilePath(this.VideoFile);
ShellProperty<ulong?> fs = shell.Properties.System.Size;

// workaround to find out if video in portrait or landscape
BitmapSource bs = shell.Thumbnail.BitmapSource;
double bsWidth = bs.Width;
double bsHeight = bs.Height;
videoOrientation = bsWidth > bsHeight ? VideoOrientation.LANDSCAPE : VideoOrientation.PORTRAIT;

ShellProperty<uint?> fw = shell.Properties.System.Video.FrameWidth;
ShellProperty<uint?> fh = shell.Properties.System.Video.FrameHeight;
```

From the code, we see that video has a thumnail representation, it is the image that you see when exploring videos in Windows Explorer.
With "fw" and "fh" you can set the aspectRatio and set the properties Width and Height od MediaElement properly.

And here in Xaml is how the Width, Height and VideoOrientation are used (Referent is the related view model):

```
<Grid Width="{Binding Referent.Width}" Height="{Binding Referent.Height}">
    <MediaElement x:Name="mediaElement" IsHitTestVisible="True" Stretch="Uniform" LoadedBehavior="Manual" UnloadedBehavior="Manual" StretchDirection="Both"
                  Visibility="Visible" ToolTip="{Binding Referent.VideoFile}"
                  Source="{Binding Referent.VideoUri}" Opacity="{Binding Opacity}" ScrubbingEnabled="True">
        <MediaElement.LayoutTransform>
            <RotateTransform CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5"
                             Angle="{Binding Referent.VideoOrientation, Converter={StaticResource OrientationRotationConverter}, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        </MediaElement.LayoutTransform>
    </MediaElement>
    <StackPanel x:Name="controlPanel" Height="18" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                Visibility="Collapsed">
        <Button Padding="0" Click="OnPlayButtonClick" Margin="3">
            <ContentControl Style="{DynamicResource PlayVideoIcon}"/>
        </Button>
        <Button Padding="0" Click="OnPauseButtonClick" Margin="3">
            <ContentControl Style="{DynamicResource PauseVideoIcon}"/>
        </Button>
        <Button Padding="0" Click="OnCloseButtonClick" Margin="3">
            <ContentControl Style="{DynamicResource CloseVideoIcon}"/>
        </Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Hope it helps somebody.

Comment: I don't see how this will rotate the MediaElement in for Portrait mode. The code looks incomplete. You define fs, videoOrientation, fw, fh, but you don't use it for anything

Comment: @PeterHuber added xaml code to the answer, hope it will help.

Comment: Thanks for the code. ffprobe shows that the video dimension is 3840x2160 (widthxheight), regardless if the video I took with my phone was in portrait or landscape mode. ffprobe shows that the video orientation information is in "side data: displaymatrix: rotation of -90.00 degrees". Since width and height recorded in the video file is the same regardless of the orientation, I wonder if WindowsAPICodePack is switching the video height and width for portrait mode ?